# How to translate some words on the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use words `vip`, `platinum`, and `general` to indicate membership, and they are scattered all over my projects. Now, I have to convert these words into Chinese.

- vip → 貴賓
- platinum → 白金
- general → 一般

I want to keep the English words in my code, and only show the translated Chinese words on the view. Is there an easy way to do this, avoiding manual replacement in my source code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rails i18n module http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

basically, you create a file with translation from a base language or key to your desired language, then, in your code, you do "t('vip')" and, if the site language is set to chinese then the view will show it on chinese, else it will show "vip"

all details are on that link

EDIT: you'll have to modify all "vip", to "t('vip')" on your code, etc, but it's actually a good practice to do that ALWAYS from the beginning so you can have a multilingual site later really easy